# Sync Drupal commerce order information

Tags: commerce, 8

Sync Drupal commerce order information between several drupal instances.

Here is my use case.

A business has a Drupal commerce website.
It also has several internal commerce sites.

Each of these has to have the ability to work independently of each other for certain periods of time.
At a later date there will be a mobile app doing the same thing.
So any sales information or orders need to be synced at later points throughout the day.

What is the recommended way to do that securely and also avoid and order related conflicts such as order number customer name changes etc?

I realize this is a fairly broad question but Im not looking for a specific answer,  Any general information or recommendations would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Some general advice:

I had a similar situation on a project. I first tried various options for importing orders from the separate sites into a central site using modules like:

1. [commerce_order_ftp_export](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_order_ftp_export)
2. [commerce_export](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_export)
3. [commerce_export_csv](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/maxgor/1863908)
4. [commerce_feeds with patch for orders](https://www.drupal.org/node/1156952)

But you will need custom code to resolve order IDs etc. Depending on the number of sites, this may be workable.

However, I eventually opted for a solution as follows:

1. Using a mobile POS app for sales
2. Sending sales from each instance of the app into a central drupal installation running maceij’s version of [commerce_marketplace](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/maciej.zgadzaj/1950386)
3. This way,sales can be separated and/or aggregated by location, POS, etc.

Comment: Could you provide some more information as to how you achieved this?

Comment: I am using a mobile app called Tabshop and used its API to write drupal module for sync with commerce. All in drupal 7. Difficult to explain everything here - better offline.

Comment: Ah ok thanks I will look into that, im using drupal 7 myself. Not sure if im skilled enough to make a module to sync with commerce but I will give it a go. Any other advice you could give would be great

Comment: Not sure we can chat offline here... But if you send me skype or whatsapp contact, we can discuss in detail.

Comment: Hi. Have you now resolved this?